# Icon Change Results in Error

Tags: vb.net, icons, unhandled-exception

I changed the icon of my `VB.net` program and now it is throwing errors.

I get this error when I try run the program:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll  Additional information: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

and it won't let me back into the designer to try and restore the original icon.  It shows a page with this message on the Ford Design page:

```
To prevent possible data loss before loading the designer, the following errors must be resolved: 

The parameter is incorrect 
Instances of this error (1)  
at System.Drawing.Icon.Initialize(Int32 width, Int32 height)
at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(Stream stream, Int32 width, Int32 height)
at System.Drawing.Icon..ctor(Stream stream)
at System.Drawing.IconConverter.ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfoculture, Object value)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.ConvertFrom(Object value)
at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GenerateObjectFromDataNodeInfo(DataNodeInfo dataNodeInfo, ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at System.Resources.ResXDataNode.GetValue(ITypeResolutionService typeResolver)
at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseDataNode(XmlTextReader reader, Boolean isMetaData)
at System.Resources.ResXResourceReader.ParseXml(XmlTextReader reader)`
```

Any suggestions?  At this point I just want to figure out how to restore the `old icon` and get going on my program again!

Comment: Go to Form1.Designer.vb and remove it from it.+

Comment: @kostasch. What do you mean "Form1.Designer.vb and remove it from it"  Visual Studio won't let me back into the Designer and if I do go in I don't know how to change the icon back.

Comment: Did you "CLEAN" the solution? Which version of VS are you using?

Comment: I mean find the file yourform.Designer.vb, find the icon you have bind with your form and remove it. Not change it, remove it. In order to see the form. Generally you must not change thing from Designer.

Comment: Remove the line  Me.Icon = ....

Comment: @kostasch. That worked perfect!  Thanks!  Any idea how I can do it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Remove the line Me.Icon = ....
```

In order to add new icon just go to your designer on properties window and add the icon you want.